# Z-index (CSS) affecting links behavior

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

i have a problem with links in a footer who's z-index is set to -1.
i can change their style via the 'a'-tag in css but they don't behave like links anymore.

here's the the html and css code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="content">
</div>
<div id="footerid" class="footer">
<div id="carrier">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<h4>About</h4>
<a href="www.google.de"><span class="pfeile">&#x25B3; </span>stuff</a><br>
<a href="d.html"><span class="pfeile">&#x25B3; </span>stuff</a><br>
<a href="d"><span class="pfeile">&#x25B3; </span>stuff</a><br>
<a href="d"><span class="pfeile">&#x25B3; </span>stuff</a><br>
</td>
<td>
<h4>Impressum</h4>
<a href="www.google.de"><span class="pfeile">&#x25B3; </span>stuff</a><br>
<a href="d"><span class="pfeile">&#x25B3; </span>stuff</a><br>
<a href="d"><span class="pfeile">&#x25B3; </span>stuff</a><br>
<a href="d"><span class="pfeile">&#x25B3; </span>stuff</a><br>
</td>
<td>
<h4>Reference</h4>
<a href="www.google.de"><span class="pfeile">&#x25B3; </span>stuff</a><br>
<a href="d"><span class="pfeile">&#x25B3; </span>stuff</a><br>
<a href="d"><span class="pfeile">&#x25B3; </span>stuff</a><br>
<a href="d"><span class="pfeile">&#x25B3; </span>stuff</a><br>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.content{
    padding: 100px 200px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: left;
}

.footer{
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 37px 0px;
    margin: 30px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    background-image: url("img/forest.jpg");
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    background-position: bottom;
    }

#carrier {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-top: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin: 0px 150px;
}
.footer h4{
    border-bottom: 1px dotted white;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    color: white;
}
.footer td{
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 150px;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline;
}

.footer a:hover {
    color: red;
}

.pfeile {
    text-decoration: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

plus an image of the resulting page:

[image: Resuting Page]

it seems that the links don't work because the z-index of the .footer container is -1.
but that has to be in order to slip under the .content container (see image)
so is there a way to make the links "accessible"?
More over the .carrier container has to be inside the .footer container!

I tried to set the z-index of the of the .carrier container to +1... which didn't work.
Of course i could set the z-index of the .content container to +1 to let the footer (with z-index 0) container slip under the content area but that again has an impact on the navigation and other containers at the top of the page...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having a negative z-index will often, if not always, disable link functionality.

Comment: Answer: don't set your footer to z-index: -1. If you need it below other elements, set them to a higher z-index.

Comment: The "link behaviour" is missing because the links are below different content due to the negative z-index. Even though they are visible, when you hover over them your mouse actualy hovers over and overlying element, different from the links.

Comment: just a quick tip, remember that z-index works only on positioned elements

Comment: thanks to everyone! i now set the content z-index to 1 and the navigations z-index to 2 (i wanted to avoid that (see last sentence) but ...)

Comment: btw. i cannot vote your comments... why is that?